# reformatting php array after database pull

Tags: php, arrays, json

Ii've got a resultset from a database pull process which includes parts of different objects of my api which I would like to reformat to my desired json format. Is there a quick way to do that?

ex. result array is of the form

```
$tasks = array ( 0=>
array(id, taskName, user_id, user_name, user_surname) ...
)
```

and would like to convert to

```
$tasks = array ( 0=>
array(id, taskName, user=> array(id, name, surname) )
)
```

Comment: yes, you build that as you retrieve rows from the db, but since you've shown no actual code, we can't help you fix what you have.

Comment: hey marc thanks for the reply. there's not much to show this is my query result from an sql query joining two tables (tasks and users) other than that that's pretty much my starting point. are you suggesting that i shouldn't start with a query of that form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "quick".  There is no pre-existing function that will do what you're wanting, and because it's a multi-dimensional array you can't return the data like that in a single query.  So it will take a few lines of code.  You could assign them each manually (assuming that `$result` is the initial array):

```
$result['user_id'] = array(
    'id'      => $result['user_id'],
    'name'    => $result['name'],
    'surname' => $result['surname']
);
```

To get exactly the end result you're looking for, you'll also want to unset the previous values after pulling from them:

```
unset $result['user_id'], $result['name'], $result['surname'];
```

If you're returning multiple rows, you'll want to do something like that in a loop.

Comment: thanks a lot Nick, that is actually what I was going for but i thought that this kind of process would add to my process time for large resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

Nick Coons beat me to it, but I will add this anyway. `array_map` would be useful here to iterate over each row and format it as you require.

```
$tasks = array_map(function ($task) {
    return [
        'id'        => $task[0],
        'task_name' => $task[1],
        'user' => [
            'id'        => $task[2],
            'user_name' => $task[3],
            'surname'   => $task[4],
        ]
    ];
}, $tasks);
```

Printing out `$tasks` would then give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [task_name] => task name
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_name] => jsmith
                    [surname] => smith
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [task_name] => task name
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_name] => jdoe
                    [surname] => doe
                )

        )

)
```